# Adding a note or message to payment?

Tags: bitcoin-core, message

I want to pay for something using bitcoin, using Bitcoin-Qt, and the seller has asked:

> Please use the order number as the note/message to receiver info.

Where do I add this info? Presumably they can't see the 'label', so where do I put this note/message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make any sense to me. There is no receiver info in Bitcoin.

Was this requested additionally to providing a recipient address? Otherwise perhaps they meant that you should use the order number as the recipient address? Perhaps the seller is just using the same email template as for wire transfer payments. – In Bitcoin sellers usually use unique addresses for each sale, so they can identify the payment through the address that they receive the money on.